# Importing function components without use in React affects rendering

Tags: reactjs

I noticed that React rendering seems to be affected by importing function components that affect rendering, even though I don't use those components. For example, in my code:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import LogIn from './Pages/Login';
import About from './Pages/About';
import Profile from './Pages/Profile';
import Feed from './Pages/Feed';
import Player from './Pages/Player';
import TradePortal from './Pages/Trading/TradePortal';
import Header from './test';


function App() {
  return (
      <Header />
  );
}

export default App;
```

I currently see this:
[image]

If I delete `import TradePortal from './Pages/Trading/TradePortal';`, I see this:
[image]

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: The file might be or add CSS rules that apply to the app

Comment: This is one reason why you get a warning in the console about unused imports.

Comment: @CertainPerformance how would that be? Would conflicting CSS class names cause this? I would think they would be localized specifically to the JS file that imports them?

Comment: @RolandoYera I used it in the past but I stopped using it due to this behavior.

Comment: Simple example, a file with CSS of `body { background-color: green }` and then `import './theFile'` will result in the rule changing the style of the body if you have a CSS loader in your bundler.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I use `.css` files that I import for each of the functional components that I import here. Is that not normal? 

Would duplicate CSS class names cause a conflict, even though I don't import two `.css` files in the same `.js` file?